# Laravel Display Picture in Profile for only Support Stuff

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an Laravel 5 Forum with an Store and i want now add an Picture (With Support Logo) in only one User Profile with DB/Mysql Status `Users-support-true`

All other Users can see the Logo but must be only display in the Support Profile.

Any one an Idea how can i do this?

I only know how i can count the Support State like this:

```
<?php $count = DB::table('users')->whereIn('support', [1])->where(['seller_id' => $product->seller->id])->count(); echo $count; ?>
```

The Support can also sell stuff.
Or can i add an Picture to DB and query it?

Thanks

Comment: please help make this question clearer. You want to show the support logo on users who are support staff?

Comment: You want to add avatar only to support user?

Comment: Yes correct:) Only for Support Stuff User Account but visible for all

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help you:

```
$users = User::where(['id' => $product->seller->id])->get();
foreach($users as $user){
$user->photo = $link_to_photo;
$user->save();
}
```

Then in views user $user->photo to show photo of user.$link_to_photo can be link to photo in file system of online image or you like to add upload something in they profile. Anything you like.

Comment: Did you have photo column in database? What it return as error? Try with changed one.